# Errors "*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!"

Tags: boot

I get the below errors when I start the system.

Now I am using the recovery mode, what should I do?

```
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem and fixed it by editing the default grub file with

```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and changing the line

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=0"
```

then saving the file and updating the grub with

```
  sudo update-grub
```

and rebooting.  If the above does not work then perhaps try out changing the

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=0"
```

to

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

.
And check the dmesg log for errors with

```
 dmesg | grep radeon
```

if the above methods work just to make sure everything is Ok.

Comment: Can you please explain why this happened in the first place? For me, in windows I see a ghost display connected, and Radeon driver will crash if I switch to it from Intel HD, but Ubuntu should have been fine.

Comment: I don't know why it happens sorry :(

Comment: I was having problems for about 4 month since upgrade to 15 and then 16 ruining lots of commands and uninstalling and installing drivers. The Bob solution seems to solve this nightmare for me. I can't believe I can see my full beautiful screen.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is not an option, it disables driver functionality, it works like a compatible mode!

Answer (score -2):

This occurs because fault in your graphic driver. First uninstall your external graphic driver. Then install latest version of your graphic driver. To explain the with more details I need to know your graphic card details.

Run this command to get display details

`sudo lshw -c display`

Comment: description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

Comment: *"uninstall your external graphic driver"* How?