# Freezing when rebooting 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, reboot

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a laptop.
This laptop had previously w7. It's a dv6 pavilion, with dedicated radeon graphics card and integrated Intel graphics.

As far as I know, this laptop is 6 years old, and the only problem it had, was that the dedicated graphics don't work anymore. Basically if you install the drivers of this dedicated graphics, it gets blue screens and doesn't work. So since I found it out, I used it with Intel graphics, and no problem.

I put Ubuntu on it, and I just updated files. As soon as I tried to restart, it got completely frozen. Turning off and on the laptop again, every time I try to reboot it, it does the same thing.

SSD 250GB, completely formatted, just with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it.

Do you think the OS is trying to communicate with the dedicated graphics and gets frozen? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I could fix it following what these guys say here, as I had the same messages when it boot the first time to install the OS: http://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu