# having issue with ubuntu 16.04 installation : looks like Graphic card / driver issue

Tags: usb-installation

I have win-7 64bit , with enough ram and memory and 1GB AMD Radeon 6470M (for ICC) .I tried to install ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit / 16.04. it keeps giving me this error "ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!"

I am new with it - so Please suggest me what should I do ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this
[Errors "*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu)

I am assuming here that you have already installed nano by:
sudo apt-get install nano

You substitute the ->"radeon"<-.modeset=0 to whatever brand your graphics card is.

Cheers,

Comment: @Pratik, did your issue got resolved?