# Samsung 730U AMD Graphic Card Driver Issue

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a problem with my SAMSUNG 730U3E laptop. My GPU is not working. I think it's not supported anymore from AMD. The AMD x64 driver is not shown on my drivers list. My computer has dual graphic card like Intel/Amd.

This is the output of `sudo lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars
[Radeon HD 8730M] [1002:6601]
```

This is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 3762.505420] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110). [
3762.586446] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down [ 3762.613557] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci [
3762.613571] usb 2-1.5: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci [ 3762.621777] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd [ 3762.655090] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs [ 3762.655094] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs [
3762.695811] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out [ 3762.696017] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 [ 3763.826509] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!! [ 3764.841866] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!! [ 3765.857212] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

This is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic
```

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu

Comment: Thank you :)) it's fix my issue