# How to reinstall Ubuntu from the live USB's command line?

Tags: grub2, live-usb, radeon, reinstall

I am not sure this is the right question to solve my problem...

I have a 8 GB SSD, where I installed Ubuntu, and a 1 TB HDD with several partitions: a big one with all my important data, a smaller one with Windows, another mounted at /opt (because 8 GB is too little for the whole system) and a couple more with around 100 GB. This has been working okay for around a year, but now I've been programming a lot and Python modules are installed at /home, so I decided to follow [this directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) and mount /home on it's own partition as well. I also deleted the Windows partitions, as I haven't used it in a while. I simply deleted them on GParted, I am not sure if that would be the right way to do it.

Which leaves us in my current situation. The system can't even load the Grub screen, and I cannot get the live USB to run with a [graphic interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu), just the command prompt. I've tried updating Grub, I've tried the "nomodeset" boot option, I've tried to move all my files back in place and use the original fstab, but nothing worked.

I'm stuck, and if there is no better option, I would like to reinstall the OS. Getting back the graphic interface on the live USB would be a great start as well.

I've been using Ubuntu for 10 years, often trying to customize it to my taste and fixing back what I broke with the help of online resources, but to be honest 30% of the time I'm not sure of what I'm doing (although I'm interested in learning from those little adventures).

My computer is a Samsung Series 7 Chronos laptop from 2012 or so, if that helps...

Comment: It was 2012 when Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode. So is your system UEFI or BIOS? And early UEFI implementations, need UEFI updates to at least newest available. Old info, but your model, may have some hints: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12382951 May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what I did wrong when trying to mount /home in another partition, but getting a new Ubuntu image in a bootable USB worked. Then I reinstalled it in a bigger partition and everything is back to normal.