# Error: UVD not responding

Tags: radeon, freeze

Since some days I get this error:

[image: error-uvd-not-responding]

```
radeon *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
```

The ThinkPad laptop seems to freeze. Only pressing the power button for several seconds helps.

After this hard power off the laptop starts. Sometimes several hard reboots are needed.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: There was a similar issue a few years ago - try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/810779/940557) if you haven't already.

Comment: I would try updating graphics drivers. I found a guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: This is a duplicate. I tried to close my own question, but I can't close it because there is a bounty running. I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu