# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting - black screen

Tags: boot, uefi, 20.04

I had 18.04 and upgraded to 20.04. At first dual boot. After installing, it showed a list of errors and never initiated the system.
I went back to 18.04, everything was OK.

Installed again, but this time leaving only 20.04. The installation was good. I didn't have any errors by the end, but when it is supposed to initiate the system I get a black screen (with Ubuntu and the logo at the bottom).

I tried to disable UEFI in the BIOS (the other option is Auto for Legacy or UEFI), but instead of the dark screen with the logo, I get a totally black screen turning on and off repeatedly.

Notebook Samsung 700z Intel Core i5

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you have nVidia, you need nomodeset to install & first boot unless you also install nVidia driver during install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  You should install in UEFI boot mode. My Asus motherboard only lets me use UEFI, if I set UEFI only. Both legacy & UEFI does not work.

Comment: How do I get to this nomodeset?
Once it is in the black screen, it doesn't accept any key or command

Comment: You have to get to grub menu, which should be possible if UEFI fast boot is off. With UEFI boot, you press escape just after or at end of UEFI boot screen, but before grub menu. Then use e on grub menu to edit boot stanza and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.  See second version on link above, first is for old BIOS boot.

Comment: It never gets to the grub menu.
It just shows the error 'uvd not responding trying to reset the vcpu' several times, then it says 'giving up' and goes to the dark screen again.
It doesnt allow me to type or do anything

Comment: This user has AMD, but had to manually edit grub. You may need to do same but use nomodeset for nVidia from live installer. Did you install nVidia driver as part of install? https://askubuntu.com/questions/717504/errors-error-uvd-not-responding-trying-to-reset-the-vcpu

Comment: I don't know. At last I gave up. Installed Fedora and Linux Mint, both working just fine, as 18.04 was. It's a shame for 20.04. I've searched through the forum and a lot of people are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

happened the same to me, I couldn't even boot 20.04 from a stick
it didn't matter the kernel options: nomodeset, noacpi etc etc
what I did was boot 18.04 from a stick, and downgrade:
grub-common=2.02-2ubuntu8.17
grub-efi-amd64=2.02-2ubuntu8.17
grub-efi-amd64-bin=2.02-2ubuntu8.17
grub-efi-amd64-signed=1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17
grub2-common=2.02-2ubuntu8.17

held the package so it doesn't update and works like a charm
with no extra kernel options at boot